# Как улучшить код по суммированию натуральных чисел?

Tags: python, циклы, инспекция-кода

Задача: Дано целое положительное число N. Выведите максимально возможную сумму последовательных целых чисел от 1 до n так, чтобы эта сумма была строго меньше заданного значения N.
Мой код:

```
n = int(input())
def get_num(n):

    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        sum += i
        if sum >= n:
            print(sum - i)
            break
    return sum
get_num(n)
```

Как можно улучшить? Задача решена конечно, но криво. Не могу понять как правильно прописать момент с суммой, где она меньше числа n. Если убрать print(sum - i), то вывод уже идет некорректный.

Comment: Эээ, человечество придумало формулу для вычисления суммы чисел от 1 до _n_. Нужно просто решить неравенство `n * (n + 1) / 2 < N`

Comment: Видите в коде `sum` красненьким подсвечено? Это потому что `sum` - встроенная функция питона. Не используйте названия встроенных функций для имён переменных. Это так - общее замечание.

Comment: если убрать ``print(sum - i)`` то вывода вообще не будет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen А его как-то можно решить? )  Или только подбирать `n` двоичным поиском, например? )  Меня `n*(n+1)` смущает. А, хотя если из него взять корень, то оно будет заведомо больше, чем `n`, можно этим воспользоваться.

Comment: @CrazyElf https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0d1d.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, исправить можно так:

```
def get_num(n):
    summ = 0
    i = 1
    while summ + i < n:
        summ += i
        i +=1
    return summ
```

А по уму вместо перебора нужно использовать формулу суммы арифметической прогрессии и решить квадратное неравенство

```
import math
def get_num2(n):
    x = math.ceil((math.sqrt(1 + 8 * n) - 1)/2) - 1
    return x*(x+1)//2
```

Comment: у численных типов, есть метод [is_integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer)

Comment: Есть же [math.floor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ну оно же не сделает 5 из 6.0

Comment: @MBo а, я там пропустил условие «строго меньше»…

Answer (score 3):

Если приводить в порядок ваш код, то надо поправить сумму перед возвращением:

```
def get_num(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        s += i
        if s >= n:
            s -= i
            break
    return s


print(get_num(int(input())))
```

`for` в решении смотрится странно. Без него будет проще:

```
def get_num(n):
    t = 0  # next term in sum
    s = 0  # current sum
    while s < n:
        t += 1
        s += t
    return s - t  # correct last term
```

Последовательное сложение не наш способ. Решим задачу аналитически.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| *∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>i < N* | исходное неравенство |
| *∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>i ≤ N - 1* | замена неравенства на нестрогое |
| *n(n + 1)/2 ≤ N - 1* | сумма арифметической прогрессии |
| *4n(n + 1) ≤ 8N - 8* |  |
| *4n<sup>2</sup> + 4n + 1 - 1 ≤ 8N - 8* |  |
| *(2n + 1)<sup>2</sup> ≤ 8N - 7* |  |
| *2n + 1 ≤ √(8N - 7)* |  |
| *2n + 1 ≤ ⌊√(8N - 7)⌋* | левая часть целая, берём из правой целую часть |
| *n ≤ (⌊√(8N - 7)⌋ - 1) / 2* |  |
| *n ≤ ⌊(⌊√(8N - 7)⌋ - 1) / 2⌋* | левая часть целая, берём из правой целую часть |

Целую часть корня *⌊√⌋* извлекает [`math.isqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt). Деление в конце *⌊... / 2⌋* целочисленное - `//`.

Можно считать:

```
def get_num(n):
    m = (math.isqrt(8 * n - 7) - 1) // 2
    return m * (m + 1) // 2
```

Comment: ... **строго меньше** заданного значения N, поэтому я и возился с точными квадратами

Comment: @MBo, вы правы. Но это поправить можно вычтя единицу из *N*.

Comment: @MBo, спасибо! Поправил вывод и код.